# Set values at ngForm in onInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a form created using ngForm and it's ok. But i need recover information saved it.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.budgetId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];

if (this.budgetId) {
  this.budgetService.detailBudget(this.budgetId).subscribe(res => {
    this.orders = res.budget.orders;
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(res.budget)) {
      this.budgetForm.value[key] = value;
    }
  })
}
}
```

But the "budgetForm" that is:

```
<form #budgetForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(budgetForm)" novalidate>
```

But, error

```
TS2339: Property 'budgetForm' does not exist on type 'BudgetRegisterComponent'.
```

How i can set the value on the form?

Comment: so where is you form?

Comment: My form is big, but it's basically this:

Comment: <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
        <app-input-forms errorMessage="Campo obrigatório" label="Título *">
          <input name="title" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="title" placeholder="Título" autocomplete="off" ngModel required>
        </app-input-forms>
      </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For set values in ngForm, use the method setValue()

```
this.budgetForm.setValue(res.budget)
```

But, before you need let the object equals the forms, field by field. I use mongo, then I need remove:

```
delete res.budget.__v
delete res.budget.__proto__
```

For exemple, before use setValue.

Thank everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have reference to your form:

```
@ViewChild('budgetForm') NgForm budgetForm;
```

You are passing the `budgetForm` in the submit method, and when `ngOnInit` runs, the `budgetForm` is undefined.

Check for null:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.budgetId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];

    if (this.budgetId && this.budgetForm) {
        this.budgetService.detailBudget(this.budgetId).subscribe(res => {
            this.orders = res.budget.orders;
            for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(res.budget)) {
                this.budgetForm.value[key] = value;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I use "@ViewChild('budgetForm') budgetForm: NgForm;" but the value of form continuos empty.

Comment: (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9oqieq) , but is error on code??? begin that it's ok.

Comment: Basically is the same think

Comment: The form continue empty on front, after set the values.

Comment: I resolve using the method setValue, thanks for help!